# How to get a table to wrap

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a page that calls a custom tag that, in turn, calls html that forms a table:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        {% for x in variable %}
            <td>
                <table class="[class]">
                    <tbody>
                    {% for y in another variable %}
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <form>
                                   [a form] 
                                   {% csrf_token %}
                                </form>
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                <form>
                                    [another form]
                                    {% csrf_token %}
                                </form>
                            </td>    
                    {% endfor %}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Is there an easy way to get this to auto-wrap when it reaches the end of a specified width or the edge of a screen?

(Note that this HTML is being generated from Django, but this isn't Django-specific).

Comment: This question has nothing to do with django, tag this with [tag:css].

Comment: are you talking about wrapping the content (displayed) or the html code?

Comment: yeah, I was talking about content -- thanks, good to know I have to use CSS

Comment: Not sanely. It sounds like you shouldn't be using tables in the first place.

Comment: Messy to do this using nested table. Try using `div` and apply CSS.